# Can't load TFLite model according to TFLite official examples

Tags: java, android, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to create a smart reply app using TFLite and I am following the  [pre-built example](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/smart_reply/android) from github.

When cloned the referenced project from git and compiled, it works flawlessly.

However , when I copy the referenced project code (also gradle dependencies, assets , libs and other stuff) to my project,
It cannot load the tflite model and throws an Runtime error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.legendsayantan.replai, PID: 14279
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for long com.legendsayantan.replai.SmartReplyClient.loadJNI(java.nio.MappedByteBuffer, java.lang.String[]) (tried Java_com_legendsayantan_replai_SmartReplyClient_loadJNI and Java_com_legendsayantan_replai_SmartReplyClient_loadJNI__Ljava_nio_MappedByteBuffer_2_3Ljava_lang_String_2)
    at com.legendsayantan.replai.SmartReplyClient.loadJNI(Native Method)
    at com.legendsayantan.replai.SmartReplyClient.loadModel(SmartReplyClient.java:64)
    at com.legendsayantan.replai.MainActivity.lambda$onStart$0(MainActivity.java:90)
    at com.legendsayantan.replai.-$$Lambda$MainActivity$Xdq7R5vPx_buuatNOneWHck6N2o.run(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:888)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8178)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1101)
```

Here is my MainActivity.java-

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;

import android.view.Menu;


import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
public static SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
public static Context context;

public static final String TAG = "SmartReply";
public static SmartReplyClient client;
public static Handler handler;
public static Interpreter model;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    context=getApplicationContext();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    client = new SmartReplyClient(getApplicationContext());
    handler = new Handler();

    sharedPreferences = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow)
            .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
            .build();
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
            || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.v(TAG, "onStart");
    handler.post(
            () -> {
               client.loadModel();
            });
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.v(TAG, "onStop");
    handler.post(
            () -> {
                client.unloadModel();
            });
}

private static void send(final String message) {
    handler.post(
            () -> {
                StringBuilder textToShow = new StringBuilder();
                textToShow.append("Input: ").append(message).append("\n\n");

                // Get suggested replies from the model.
                SmartReply[] ans = client.predict(new String[] {message});
                for (SmartReply reply : ans) {
                    textToShow.append("Reply: ").append(reply.getText()).append("\n");
                }
                textToShow.append("------").append("\n");


            });
      }
}
```

And here is SmartReplyClient.java (Exact Same file as the reference github project):

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor;

import androidx.annotation.Keep;
import androidx.annotation.WorkerThread;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.MappedByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class SmartReplyClient implements AutoCloseable {
  private static final String TAG = "SmartReplyDemo";
  private static final String MODEL_PATH = "smartreply.tflite";
  private static final String BACKOFF_PATH = "backoff_response.txt";
  private static final String JNI_LIB = "smartreply_jni";

  private final Context context;
  private long storage;
  private MappedByteBuffer model;

  private volatile boolean isLibraryLoaded;

  public SmartReplyClient(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
  }

  public boolean isLoaded() {
    return storage != 0;
  }

  @WorkerThread
  public synchronized void loadModel() {
    if (!isLibraryLoaded) {
      System.loadLibrary(JNI_LIB);
      isLibraryLoaded = true;
    }

    try {
      model = loadModelFile();
      String[] backoff = loadBackoffList();
      storage = loadJNI(model, backoff); //This line is throwing the error
      // But this same java file works nice in the reference project
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
      return;
    }
  }

  @WorkerThread
  public synchronized SmartReply[] predict(String[] input) {
    if (storage != 0) {
      return predictJNI(storage, input);
    } else {
      return new SmartReply[] {};
    }
  }

  @WorkerThread
  public synchronized void unloadModel() {
     close();
  }

  @Override
  public synchronized void close() {
    if (storage != 0) {
      unloadJNI(storage);
      storage = 0;
    }
  }

  public MappedByteBuffer loadModelFile() throws IOException {
     try (AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor =
         AssetsUtil.getAssetFileDescriptorOrCached(context, MODEL_PATH);
         FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor())) {
         FileChannel fileChannel = inputStream.getChannel();
         long startOffset = fileDescriptor.getStartOffset();
         long declaredLength = fileDescriptor.getDeclaredLength();
         return fileChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, startOffset, declaredLength);
     }
  }

   private String[] loadBackoffList() throws IOException {
    List<String> labelList = new ArrayList<String>();
    try (BufferedReader reader =
        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(context.getAssets().open(BACKOFF_PATH)))) {
      String line;
      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        if (!line.isEmpty()) {
          labelList.add(line);
        }
      }
    }
    String[] ans = new String[labelList.size()];
    labelList.toArray(ans);
    return ans;
  }

  @Keep
  private native long loadJNI(MappedByteBuffer buffer, String[] backoff);

  @Keep
  private native SmartReply[] predictJNI(long storage, String[] text);

  @Keep
  private native void unloadJNI(long storage);
}
```

I also implemented the same tensorflow version in `build.gradle`  as the reference example:

```
implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:0.0.0-nightly-SNAPSHOT'
```

**Here , it throws the error mentioned above.**

To avoid the error , I also tried to load the TFLite model using `Interpreter`
in activity `onCreate`:

```
Interpreter interpreter;
        try {
            interpreter=new Interpreter(loadmodelfile());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Method `loadmodelfile()`:

```
public MappedByteBuffer loadmodelfile() throws IOException {
        AssetFileDescriptor assetFileDescriptor = this.getAssets().openFd("smartreply.tflite");
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(assetFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor());
        FileChannel fileChannel = fileInputStream.getChannel();
        long startoff = assetFileDescriptor.getStartOffset();
        long length = assetFileDescriptor.getDeclaredLength();
        return fileChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY,startoff,length);
    }
```

Still there, I got this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.legendsayantan.tflitesmartreplyremake, PID: 10879
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.legendsayantan.tflitesmartreplyremake/com.legendsayantan.tflitesmartreplyremake.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Internal error: Unexpected failure when preparing tensor allocations: Encountered unresolved custom op: Normalize.
    Node number 0 (Normalize) failed to prepare.
    
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3782)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3961)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:91)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:149)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:103)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2386)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8178)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1101)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Internal error: Unexpected failure when preparing tensor allocations: Encountered unresolved custom op: Normalize.
    Node number 0 (Normalize) failed to prepare.
```

Please let me know about something I am missing or any mistakes I made in any of those attempts.

I am newbie at Tensorflow but not newbie at creating android apps, I just can't figure out what other thing have I mistaken here .

Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi Legend the first error is different than the second with the Interpreter. The first one is due to copy pasting code but the second is telling something about a missing operator. Please point a web link to clone and debug the project.

Comment: Here is the [first project](https://github.com/legendsayantan/TFLiteSmartReplyRemake) in which I tried to copy paste , and here is the [second project](https://github.com/legendsayantan/TFLiteSmartReplyRemake2) trying to load the model using `Interpreter`.

Comment: @farmaker At first project, the github reference and my code both have `@Keep` annotation for `loadJNI` because this would be accessed through reflection to prevent the compiler from treating the code as unused. There's not a single other usage for `loadJNI`  than showed in the SmartReplyClient.java , both in reference and in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Encountered unresolved custom op: Normalize.

Looks like your model has a custom op, Normalize, which means that you need to implement your own TFLite custom op and register it to the TFLite interpreter. If you have no plans to implement the custom op, please consider using the Select TF op option, which can leverage the TensorFlow ops on mobile.

https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_select